# How to get rid of yellow screen of death in asp.net mvc without using customErrors

Tags: asp.net, iis

If there is something entirely wrong with the startup in asp.net mvc the application cannot start up, and I would like to handle it properly. The customErrors tag in web.config sends a 302 which I don't like because it is not semanticly correct, which makes logging etc more complicated. Also the 302 does not have a Cache-Control: private unlike all other requests in asp.net which can cause the error to be cached in upstream proxies.

Is there another way to get rid of the YSOD for application startup errors. It should just return a plain 500.

Comment: In my opinion, there is no other way to get rid of YSOD. it's Http.sys throw error. you could try to sue the iis error pages. select site name then click on the error pages featureimage1 then ->edit feature setting->detailed errors image2. you can also set custom error pages in iis.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2008/05/27/iis-7-0-http-error-pages/

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: I put default ttl in cloudfront to 0 which solved the immediate issue, but I would still like to have better control of this.

Comment: I request you to post the solution and mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.